# Как преобразовать компоненты url в get-параметры

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

```
Собственно эта фигня замечательно работает, все гуд.
```

Обращаемся по урл [http://мойсайт.cool/turnkey_solutions/id](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.cool/turnkey_solutions/id)
И срабатывает  typeSolution.php в котором через get берем id.

```
location  /turnkey_solutions{
      rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)$ /typeSolution.php?id=$1;
     }
```

Я хочу по урл [http://мойсайт.cool/turnkey_solutions/id/solutionsid](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.cool/turnkey_solutions/id/solutionsid)
обрабатывать скрипт solution.php где я бы брал get id и solutionsid
Как это сделать?
Попробовал с несколько десятков различных махинаций и комбинаций впустую.

```
#rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)$ /typeSolution.php?ID=$1;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)/(.*)$ /solution.php?ID=$1&name=$2;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)/(.*)$ /solution.php?value1=$1&value2=$2;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/$ /typeSolution.php?value1=$1;
  #rewrite ^(.+?/)(.*)/$ /solution.php?value1=$1&value2=$2 permanent;
  #rewrite ^(.+?/)(.*)$  /solution.php?value1=$1&value2=$2 permanent;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)$ /solution.php?ID=$1&ID2=$2&ID3=$3;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ /typeSolution.php?rt=$1;
  #rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*)$ /typeSolution.php?ID=$1;
```

Это кусочек моих неудачных опытов(я знаю что они не дурные)

Comment: у вас срабатывает сразу первое правило,и все остальные лесом идут. а в первом не хватает `?` после первой звездочки. да и звездочку лучше на плюс заменить. А если id это числа то `... /(\d+)/(\d+)`, т.к. точка соответствует вообще любому  символу

Comment: `rewrite ^/turnkey_solutions/(.*?)/?(.+?)/?$ /typeSolution.php?id=$1&solutionsid=$2;`

Comment: @teran нет, в моем случае идентификатор не число. Спасибо.